# external url for post thumbnail and title

Tags: permalinks, thumbnails

I created a custom category template where I show thumbnails of the posts and a title as url, if you click on the thumbnail or the title you get redirected to the post but I would like to redirect to an external website when you click either on the image or the url.

Wordpress doesn't let me set an external URL. No clue how to tackle that, couldn't find the right plugin and I would like to learn some coding anyway. I am an absolute Beginner.

Comment: I use the "Page Links To" plugin. It adds an extra metabox to each post allowing you to send the post to a custom URL. Simple, but it works great.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thx :)
How do I "close this" now ? Since you only wrote a comment it seems I cant accept it

Comment: i am glad it works for you. I added my comment as an answer.

Comment: recommendations aren't in this stacks scope, depending on what's needed though it should be possible to filter the permalink and use a value from a post meta field/metabox instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use the "Page Links To" plugin. It adds an extra metabox to each post allowing you to send the post to a custom URL. Simple, but it works great.

Comment: the "Page Links To" plugin does redirect to a page, but when I click into "open in a new tab", it doesn't open. do you know why?

Comment: @Fernando if you have a new question please use the ask a question button, don't post it as the solution to someone elses. In this case though you should ask on the page links to plugin support, questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here

Comment: This solution isn't an answer, it's a recommendation. Answers must be self contained